# Find the limit of $n \ (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the limit of $n \ (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1) $.

Wolfram says it is $+\infty$.

Obviously $n \rightarrow +\infty$ and $\sqrt[n]{n} - 1\rightarrow 0$.

Any hint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint** 
$$
 n \ (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)={e^{(\ln n)/n}-1\over (\ln n)/n}\ln n.
$$

Comment: I don't get this transformation.

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{n}=n^{1/n}=\exp(\ln(n^{1/n}))=\exp({1\over n}\ln n)$

Comment: but how did you get $ln {\frac{n}{n}}$ ?

Comment: The parentheses are missing, it's $\frac{\ln n}{n}$.

Comment: Ok. I see. And $\frac{e^{(\ln n)/n}-1}{ (\ln n)/n}\ln n$ diverges to what?

Comment: Look at the two factors: $\ln n$ goes to infinity; and $\frac{e^h-1}{h}=\frac{e^h-e^0}{h-0}\to \exp^\prime(0) = e^0 = 1$ (note that $h=\frac{\ln n}{n}\to 0$).

Answer (score 2):

With Taylor approximations, using the facts that (i) $e^x = 1+x +o(x)$ when $x\to 0$, (ii) $\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$, and (iii) ${\frac{\ln n}{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$:

*(See below for a full, detailed derivation; stop here if you just wanted a hint.)*

---

> $$\begin{align}n\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right) &= n\left(e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1\right)= n\left(1+\frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)-1\right) \\&= n\left(\frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)= \ln n + o(\ln n)\end{align}$$and since $\ln n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$ you can conclude by comparison.

Comment: I'll come back here after I cover Tayler approximation in calculus class :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n^\frac1n-1)}{\frac1n}$$

Using Hopital

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\frac1n}\frac1{n^2}\times (-\ln n +1)}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac1n}(\ln n -1)$$

Comment: What exactly are your "=" signs referring to? This should be the *limits* that are equated, yet here the parsing would suggest it's the actual quantities.

Comment: @ClementC. I mean the second phrase and the third one are equal to the first phrase.

Comment: No -- their *limits* are equal but they are not themselves equal.

Comment: @ClementC. Nice point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$n(\sqrt[n] n-1)= \frac {\sqrt[n] n-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Then applying L'Hôpital's rule, one has (after simplification in numerator and denominator of the factor $\frac{1}{n^2}$ which  I can't arrive to write in Tex Commands) $$\frac{-n^{1/n}(\ln n-1)}{-1}$$ and this expression clearly tends to $+\infty$ when $n\to\infty$