# Elementary proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

This question is closely related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527215/find-the-limit-of-n-sqrtnn-1), but I am not happy with the answers there for several reasons which I will explain in a second.

The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=\infty$, where $n$ is a natural number, is easy to see by expanding the left side with the help of the exponential series. Indeed, we have
$$
n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=\ln(n)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\cdot\ln(n)^2+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\ln(n)^3+\cdots\geq\ln(n)\,.
$$
Since $\ln(n)$ grows arbitrary large with $n$ large, the limit is proven.

I found this limit as an exercise in Analysis 1 by K. Königsberger, 5.8 Exercises, 3(b). I am using an old printing and the numbering might have changed, but it is in the very beginning of the book in a chapter about sequences.

At that stage of the book the exponential series as well as logarithms have not yet been introduced and very few means are available. For educational purposes, I am looking for a really elementary proof which uses a different bound from below which in turn goes to infinity. The book suggests that such a proof must exist but I cannot find one.

Can you please help me to find such proof? What is available at this stage is the Bernoulli inequality and the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ for a natural number $n$ and arbitrary $x$, plus some very basic limits like $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$, etc. which all can be done elementary. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What about writing $$n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) = \log(n) \left( \dfrac{e^{\log(n)/n}-1}{\log(n)/n}\right)$$ and then using the very elementary limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=1\quad ?$$

Comment: This uses the exponential function and logarithms which have not been introduced.

Comment: Are you allowed to use $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^x = 1$$ and L'Hospital?

Comment: No, this L'Hopital's theorem is definitely not allowed. You should only use limits which are indexed by natural numbers.

Comment: You really want $\alpha_n=\sqrt[2]{n}>\frac{\log n}{n}.$ The base of the natural log is the sticking point, at heart. In elementary arguments, you might show:

$$\alpha_n > \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$
or maybe:
$$\alpha_n >\frac{\log_2 n}{n}$$

Comment: For example, $2^a>1+a$ for $a$ large and the existence of $\log_2 x$ for $x$ real.

Comment: I was wrong about $\log_2n, you need $a_n>\frac{log_3 n}{n}.$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For each $M \in \mathbb{R}$, choose positive integers $k$ and $N$ so that $\frac{k}{2} > M$ and $N = 2^k$. Then for each $n \geq N$, we have

\begin{align*}
n \bigl( n^{1/n} - 1 \bigr)
&\geq n \bigl( 2^{k/n} - 1 \bigr) \\
&= n \cdot \frac{2^{k/n} - 1}{2^{n/n} - 1} \\
&= n \cdot \frac{1 + 2^{1/n} + \cdots + 2^{(k-1)/n}}{1 + 2^{1/n} + \cdots + 2^{(n-1)/n}} \\
&\geq n \cdot \frac{k}{2n} = \frac{k}{2} > M
\end{align*}

and therefore the sequence diverges to $+\infty$.

---

*Remark.* Note that the above argument essentially proves the inequality

$$ n \bigl( n^{1/n} - 1 \bigr) \geq \frac{1}{2}\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor, $$

so we can't really avoid the logarithm from entering this picture, as @Thomas Andrews anticipated.

Comment: To downvoters: Would you please let me know what is not good about my answer so that I can improve it?

Comment: I don't know why you were dowvoted, but it may help to emphasize why$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^{j/n}\ge k,\,\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{j/n}\le 2n$$(namely, because terms in the first (second) sum are $\ge1$ ($\le2$)).

Comment: My A dekes around the logarithms. Interestingly, John Napier developed logarithms in the 1500's before there was a general theory of exponents. Oceanic navigation requires spherical trigonometry, which entails much multiplying.

Comment: (+1) and accepted. Thank you! This is the proof I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

You only need the $\text{HM}\leq\text{GM}\leq\text{AM}$ inequality and few other ingredients (harmonic numbers). 
For any natural number $n\geq 2$ we have
$$ n = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \tag{TelescopicProduct}$$
hence
$$ \sqrt[n]{n}=GM\left(1,1+1,1+\frac{1}{2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) $$
is upper bounded by
$$AM\left(1,1+1,1+\frac{1}{2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)=1+\frac{H_{n-1}}{n} $$
and lower bounded by
$$HM\left(1,1+1,1+\frac{1}{2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)=\frac{n}{n+1-H_n}$$
hence
$$ \sqrt[n]{n}-1 \geq \frac{(H_n-1)}{n-(H_n-1)}\geq \frac{H_n-1}{n} $$
and $n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ is clearly divergent.

Comment: (+1) This is a nice trick :)

Comment: (+1) Nice, thank you. I accepted the other answer because it uses even less preliminaries.

Comment: (+1) This gives a good lower bound since $n\left(x^{1/n}-1\right)$ decreases to $\log(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show it converges to infinity if you known:

> **Lemma:** For any real $C>0,$ the sequence $$\left(1+\frac{C}n\right)^n$$ is bounded above.

Given this lemma, we can prove your result, because:

$$\begin{align}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)&>C\iff \\n\sqrt[n]{n}&> n+C\iff\\n^{n+1}&>(C+n)^{n}\iff\\ n&>\left(1+\frac Cn\right)^n\end{align}$$

By the lemma, when $n$ is large enough,  this last inequality is true.

**Proof of lemma:**

We use that:

$$\binom{m}{k}\leq\frac{m^k}{k!}\tag 1$$ and, for $n\geq m,$ $$n!\geq m^{n-m} m!.\tag2$$ These two are equivalent, and easily proven.

Then we choose some $n_0>C.$

For $n\geq n_0,$ we have: $$\begin{align}\left(1+\frac Cn\right)^{n}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk\frac{C^k}{n^k}\\&\leq\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{C^k}{k!}\\&\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n_0-1}\frac{C^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=n_0}^\infty\frac{C^k}{n_0!n_0^{k-n_0}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n_0-1} \frac{C^k}{k!}+\frac{C^{n_0}}{n_0!}\frac{1}{1-\frac{C}{n_0}}
\end{align}$$

---

Note, although this answer is essentially proving the power series for $e^C$ converges, we don't need to know that this power series is the limit, nor anything about the function $e^x.$

Nor do we need that $(1+C/n)^n$ converges.

Comment: I wonder if there is a combinatorial approach, when $C$ is a positive integer. We know, since $(1+C/n)^n<e^{C}$ that also:

$$\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^n\leq 4^{C}$$ or equivalently $$(n+C)^{n}\leq 4^Cn^{n}.$$ 

Let $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,C\},$ $N=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}.$ Then the left side counts all functions $N\to N\sqcup A.$ The right side counts all pairs of functions $(f,S)$ where $f:B\to B$ and $S\subseteq A\times\{1,2\}.$  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: (+1) Another way to show that $\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^n$ is bounded above is to show that $\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^{n+C}$ is non-increasing. Then $$\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^n\le\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^{n+C}\le(1+C)^{1+C}$$ This is shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n^{1/n}=1+d_n.$ If $nd_n\not\to\infty$ then there exists $k>0$ such that $d_n<k/n$ for infinitely many $n.$  If $d_n<k/n$  then by the Binomial Theorem $$n=(1+d_n)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n(d_n)^j\binom n j \le$$ $$\le\sum_{j=0}^n(k/n)^j\binom n j\le$$  $$\le\sum_{j=0}^nk^j/ j!<$$ $$<\sum_{j=0}^
{\infty}k^j/j!.$$ But the last series (above) is convergent because when $j>2k$ the ratio of successive terms $\frac { k^{j+1}/ (j+1)!}{k^j/ j!}$ is less than $1/2.$

So if $nd_n\not\to\infty$ then there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ that are less than the real number $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}k^j/ j!,$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

For $n,x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\ge1$ and $x\ge0$,
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}\ge\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+x+1}\tag1
$$
That is, $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}$ is non-increasing in $n$. A proof of $(1)$, using only Bernoulli's Inequality, is given below.

Suppose that
$$
n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)\le x\tag2
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
n
&\le\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\tag{3a}\\
&\le\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&\le(1+x)^{1+x}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: follows directly from $(2)$
$\phantom{\text{(3a):}}$ (divide by $n$, add $1$, and raise to the $n^\text{th}$ power)
$\text{(3b)}$: multiply by $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^x\ge1$
$\text{(3c)}$: apply $(1)$ ($n-1$ times)

Thus, we have shown that
$$
n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)\le x\implies n\le(1+x)^{1+x}\tag4
$$
The contrapositive of $(4)$, which is equivalent to $(4)$, is
$$
n\gt(1+x)^{1+x}\implies n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)\gt x\tag5
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)=\infty}\tag6
$$

---

**Proof of $\bf{(1)}$** (repurposed from $(2)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2698466))

For $n,x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\ge1$ and $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+x+1}}
&=\left(\frac{n+x}{n}\right)^{n+x}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+x+1}\right)^{n+x+1}\tag{7a}\\
&=\frac{n}{n+x}\left(\frac{n+x}{n}\frac{n+1}{n+x+1}\right)^{n+x+1}\tag{7b}\\
&=\frac{n}{n+x}\left(\frac{n^2+(x+1)n+x}{n^2+(x+1)n}\right)^{n+x+1}\tag{7c}\\
&=\frac{n}{n+x}\left(1+\frac{x}{(n+x+1)n}\right)^{n+x+1}\tag{7d}\\[3pt]
&\ge\frac{n}{n+x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\tag{7e}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{7f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a)}$-$\text{(7d)}$: algebraic manipulation
$\text{(7e)}$: [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$\text{(7f)}$: simplification

Comment: Would the downvoter, who downvoted during the 2 minutes before I deleted the erroneous answer, care to reevaluate the edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

By way of contradiction suppose it does not converge to $\infty$. Then there exists a subsequence $n_k$ with $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} n_k = \infty$ s.t. $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} n_k\left(n_k^{1/n_k}-1\right) < \infty$$
i.e.
$$n_k\left(n_k^{1/n_k}-1\right) < c \\
n_k < \left(1+\frac{c}{n_k}\right)^{n_k}$$
$\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ and some $c>0$.

Then use $$\left(1+x/n\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n}{n}\frac{(n-1)}{n}\cdots\frac{(n-k+1)}{n} \, \frac{x^k}{k!} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
and the RHS clearly converges since $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^{k+1}/(k+1)!}{x^k/k!} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{k+1}=0<1 \,.$$

Comment: I think Thomas Andrews' point is that just because the sequence does not converge to $+\infty$ it doesn't mean that it converges to a finite value, it could not converge at all. However, this is not an issue, you can pass to subsequence that converges and carry out your argument for that converging subsequence.

Comment: Yes, I get his point, but I'm just saying that it is bounded by some constant...

Comment: That needs not be true, you could have subsequences, that go to $+\infty$. Consider the sequence $x_{2n}=2n$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$. It does not converge to $+\infty$, but it is also not bounded.

Comment: The sequence is monotonic. If it is bounded, it has a limit.

Comment: @user213008 How would you show that the sequence is monotone if you cannot use any property of the logarithm?

Comment: I see that this answer is promising. To derive a contradiction, we may assume that $$c=\sup_n n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)$$ is finite and then show that $(1+\frac{c}{n})^n$ is bounded, thereby contradicting the inequality $n\leq(1+\frac{c}{n})^n$ for all $n$. This can be done by using the binomial theorem to expand $$\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{c^k}{n^k}\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c^k}{k!}. $$ It is then easy to show that this bound remains finite as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Originally I meant to write $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right) < \infty \, $$ but I somehow mixed everything up when writing it down, so it ended up to be $\lim$ and then $\limsup$ instead in the hassle...  From this it follows there exists $c>0$ s.t. $$\inf_{k\geq n} k\left(k^{1/k}-1\right) < c$$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. The rest is basically along the lines as now. But instead of unproductive complaining, you could have just pointed it out directly...

Comment: @SangchulLee We don't know if $$c=\sup_n n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)$$ exists as SeverinSchravens answer makes clear. I think that was the whole problem that arose originally.

Comment: @Diger, The *supremum* always exists, but I agree with you that $\sup_{n\geq 1} n(n^{1/n}-1)=\infty$ does not necessarily imply $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(n^{1/n}-1)=\infty$ I realized this when you updated your answer, so thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. $c=\infty$ for the supremum doesn't help and the limit could not exist at all. On the other hand $\liminf$ always exists and that is sufficient for this problem.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that my A is basically the same as yours.